# How to display the MQTT values in UI through Django framework

Tags: python, html, django, macos, mqtt

I am trying to get the values from the MQTT broker and wanted to display the values in the web UI through the Django framework. I have all the code files. I don't know where to place the python MQTT code to get the values from the broker to pass it to the UI.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created the environment for Django and have implemented the web 
UI through Django framework

Comment: It is expected that provide some code that show an attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Implemented the UI through Django but I don't know how to get the values from the MQTT Broker and display it in UI, like just displaying the UI in Django framework. I have attached the screenshot below

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot of displaying UI via Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRg75.png)